# Appending file data at the end of second file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to append text at the end of the file. When I am doing now, I am getting blank spaces between each read character.
Snippet:

```
os.system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File securepwd.ps1 " +pwd)
f1 = open("SecondFile.txt","r")
passwd = f1.read()
f = open("Myfile.txt","w")
details="orginal text"+passwd
f.write(details)
```

The securepwd.ps1 generates encrypted text & paste the contents in secondfile.txt
I want to append the contents in secondfile.txt to Myfile.txt.

The output I am getting by running above is as below:
uname:nehaS
password: **ÿþ0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 d 0 8 c 9 d d f 0 1 1 5 d 1 1 1 8 c 7 a 0 0 c 0 4 f c 2 9 7 e b 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 c 1 f 6 b f 0 4 6 6 0 5 7 c 4 d 9 3 9 3 9 4 e 5 2 1 6 d 1 8 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 f 9 b 3 b d e 8 2 2 3 d e c f f e e a 4 7 e 6 3 c 8 6 0 6 c b 1 5 a 1 b 8 c 5 d 3 2 d 4 4 4 0 d c 5 c b e 6 c 8 0 5 8 4 d 5 5 a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 e 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a d 3 6 f 3 7 2 f 8 6 6 0 8 8 f 6 b b 9 3 a 3 6 4 a 4 8 2 f 4 f 0 b 1 1 8 5 a e 3 1 0 5 6 e 8 c 2 6 4 0 a a**

The bold part is the contents from secondfile.txt.

The actual content is secondfile.txt is as below
**01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c1f6bf0466057c4d939394e5216d186700000000020000000000106600000001000020000000f9b3bde8223decffeea47e63c8606cb15a1b8c5d32d4440dc5cbe6c80584d55a000000000e8000000002000020000000ad36f372f866088f6bb93a364a482f4f0b1185ae31056e8c2640aa**

I want the output like **uname:nehaS password:01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c1f6bf0466057c4d939394e5216d186700000000020000000000106600000001000020000000f9b3bde8223decffeea47e63c8606cb15a1b8c5d32d4440dc5cbe6c80584d55a000000000e8000000002000020000000ad36f372f866088f6bb93a364a482f4f0b1185ae31056e8c2640aa**

Why is it taking unnecessary spaces? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you make the question a little clearer, and improve your [MRE], also what do you want to output to look like?, to test everything first try keeping the input file data to something simple so you can understand what is happening.

Comment: I want the output like uname:nehaS password:01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c1f6bf0466057c4d939394e5216d186700000000020000000000106600000001000020000000f9b3bde8223decffeea47e63c8606cb15a1b8c5d32d4440dc5cbe6c80584d55a000000000e8000000002000020000000ad36f372f866088f6bb93a364a482f4f0b1185ae31056e8c2640aa

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. My friend helped in this. He gave me crypted exe file which encrypted the usual text to encrypted, which I append in the file. Below is the solution

```
f = open("Myfile.txt","w")
details="original text"
f.write(details)
f.close()
os.system("cryptxt.exe " +pwd+" >> Myfile.txt")
```